# can anyone explain how does this code work? pandas in python

Tags: pandas

```
`
for column in list(df.columns[df.isnull().sum() > 0]):
    mean = df[column].mean()
    df[column].fillna(mean,inplace=True)
df.info()`
```

i don't understand the first line of code, i mean,  ... **list**() ... does it means everything in the parenthesis will be return to the **list**?
should it be written like:

```
list = df.columns[df.isnull().sum() > 0]
for column in list:
....
```

here, how could Python know what's inside of *df.columns[df.isnull().sum() > 0]* ,

for me i will write like,

```
sum = 0
for each in df.columns:
    if each is null:
    sum += 1 (which is wrong obviously, but you know what i mean)
```

...

i am a beginner in Python, and i used to write in C, so it's confusing , hope someone can help me explain the way of using parenthesis to range the list, how does it work in Python.

thanks very much.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` here convert `Index` (columns names with at least one `NaN`) to `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,np.nan,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,np.nan,np.nan,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C    D    E  F
0  a  4  7  1.0  5.0  a
1  b  5  8  NaN  NaN  a
2  c  4  9  5.0  NaN  a
3  d  5  4  7.0  9.0  b
4  e  5  2  1.0  2.0  b
5  f  4  3  0.0  4.0  b
```

---

```
a = list(df.columns[df.isnull().sum() > 0])
print (a)
['D', 'E']

print (df.isnull().sum())
A    0
B    0
C    0
D    1
E    2
F    0
dtype: int64

print (df.isnull().sum() > 0)
A    False
B    False
C    False
D     True
E     True
F    False
dtype: bool

print (df.columns[df.isnull().sum() > 0])
Index(['D', 'E'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: thanks!  it's very helpful for understanding the list!

Comment: @JuncaiLiu - Glad can help!